# How can I divert an incoming call from dialplan to a http server via ESL freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I am building an app with ESL which can originate calls, I see that ESL also has capabilities to answer call and playback some music. How should I change my xml dialplan so that the call gets diverted to this ESL app(hosted as a server either locally or in public)

I see that freeswitch docs example ask to directly use Lua scripts and direct calls.